# Can't get FCM payload message on Android app after website publish on Openshift

Tags: java, android, servlets, openshift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a JSP Servlet Web application, when customer enter one entry using web application the application generate the FCM payload message to Android application.
It's all working fine when I tested it on my local environment, but now I published the website on OPENSHIFT and try to enter one entry using website.
Now I am unable to get the FCM payload message on my Android app. What could be the problem? My android app is not published on Google play store yet.
I used all required code i.e.

public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

It works fine on any machine but after publishing the website on OPENSHIFT it's not send any message to Android app.

```
// This class is created to send data payload to the FCM to Android app....
public class SendDataPayload {
// Method to send Notifications from server to client end.

public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

// userDeviceIdKey is the device id you will query from your database
public void pushFCMNotification(String userDeviceIdKey, int y_Id, String f_name, String l_name, String m_number,
        String puja_name, String puja_date, String puja_time, String p_address, String p_landmark, String p_taluka,
        String p_district, String p_pincode) throws Exception {

    String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM; // Your FCM AUTH key
    String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM;

URL url = new URL(FMCurl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + authKey);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("to", userDeviceIdKey.trim()); // device token...

    // JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
    // info.put("title", "xyz"); // Notification title
    // info.put("body", "my message body is here!!!");
    // // Notification body
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  hh:mm a").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    String date = timeStamp;

    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    String first_name_ = URLEncoder.encode(f_name, "UTF-8");
    String last_name_ = URLEncoder.encode(l_name, "UTF-8");
    String santrika_sandesh = URLEncoder.encode("msg-MY", "UTF-8");
    String M_number = URLEncoder.encode(m_number, "UTF-8");
    String Puja_name = URLEncoder.encode(puja_name, "UTF-8");
    String Puja_date = URLEncoder.encode(puja_date, "UTF-8");
    String Puja_time = URLEncoder.encode(puja_time, "UTF-8");
    String P_address = URLEncoder.encode(p_address, "UTF-8");
    String P_landmark = URLEncoder.encode(p_landmark, "UTF-8");
    String P_taluka = URLEncoder.encode(p_taluka, "UTF-8");
    String P_district = URLEncoder.encode(p_district, "UTF-8");

    data.put("key1", santrika_sandesh); // DataPayload
    data.put("key2", date); // DataPayload
    data.put("y_Id", y_Id);
    data.put("f_name", first_name_); // Yajman first name
    data.put("l_name", last_name_);
    data.put("m_number", M_number);
    data.put("puja_name", Puja_name);
    data.put("puja_date", Puja_date);
    data.put("puja_time", Puja_time);
    data.put("puja_add", P_address);
    data.put("puja_landmark", P_landmark);
    data.put("puja_tal", P_taluka);
    data.put("puja_dist", P_district);
    data.put("puja_pincode", p_pincode);

    // send notification and payload data to FCM....
    // json.put("notification", info);
    json.put("data", data);

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(json.toString());
    wr.flush();
    conn.getInputStream();
}
```

}

Comment: add code in question and also add the response message from firebase server

Comment: not any response message from Firebase server. But when i run it on my local machine or any other machines it works fine. problem is given when website is publish on OPENSHIFT.

Comment: Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_response FCM will send back http response with success or errror

Comment: Example {"multicast_id":************,"success":1,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:***********"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_response

FCM will send back http response with success or error.

FCM response Example {"multicast_id":************,"success":1,"failure":1,"canoni‌cal_ids":0,"results"‌​:[{"error":"NotRegis‌​tered"},{"message_id‌​":"0:***********"}]}

In code below fcmServerResponse.toString() is response from FCM.Print it in webpage so can see the error or success message.

```
StringBuilder fcmServerResponse = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine;


                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    fcmServerResponse.append(inputLine);
                }

     fcmServerResponse.toString()//This is response from FCM
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, i run this code in local machine i got following output {"multicast_id":6315909649349302325,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1493277577552356%8c21b8c8f9fd7ecd"}]}       my message is send successfully on android app

Comment: @Rajeshchopade what output did you get in openshift

Comment: Actually openshift is run by third party I don't have credentials, what is meaning of above response my message is successfully delivered or not?

Comment: @Rajeshchopade You said in question that it was not working in openshift so in my answer i added code to display Response from firebase which looks something like this  {"multicast_id":************,"success":1,"failure":1,"canoni‌cal_ids":0,"results"‌​:[{"error":"NotRegis‌​tered"},{"message_id‌​":"0:***********"}]}

Comment: @Rajeshchopade 
     use fcmServerResponse.toString() String to display it in webpage so we can see message(example: {"multicast_id":************,"success":1,"failure":1,"canoni‌​‌cal_ids":0,"results‌​"‌​:[{"error":"NotRe‌​gis‌​tered"},{"messa‌​ge_id‌​":"0:********‌​***"}]} ) when running from openshift

Comment: yes, it not works in OPENSHIFT means i am not able to get the FCM payload messages on Android app when application run on OPENSHIFT. I will check it on OPENSHIFT and come to you. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Rajeshchopade deploy in openshift and see webpage which display fcmServerResponse.toString() so we can know what happen while using openshift